# Having all credential of remote system, navigate to one known application on remote system,few clicks on that application and get ScreenShoot remotely

Tags: remote-access

I know the credential of remote system by using any Remote Desktop connection like teamViewer / anydesk or any other, and having all access to me need few things to perform on remote system

1. on remote system, navigate to application which is on remote system installed for example:- say "ABC",
   on ABC I want to few clicks on different menu's or tabs of the ABC, take a screen shoot of ABC application at different places.
2. and get that screen shoot.

**Inshort** go to remote system's YY application and click on different tabs on that YY application , take screen shoot and get those screen shoot to me,
A automatic tool or process

Guide me How to do that

Comment: I suggest rephrasing the question title a little: the fact that you have credentials is not as important as which operating system is on the machine (you mention Remote Desktop, I presume it is Windows?). What prevented you to take this screenshot so far (taking screenshot from Remote Desktop window seems easy enough?)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.